# Calling Finder's "Import from iPhone > Take Photo" from shell

Tags: macos, shell, applescript, finder, macos-mojave

Does anyone know how to call the following from shell?

```
Right Click > Import from iPhone > Take Photo
```

I suspect it has something to do with: `defaults write com.apple.finder`. Can I achieve that via AppleScript? I looked into the Finder library documentation and I haven't found any interface related to what I am looking for.

---

*Screen capture*

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I edited the question by adding a screen capture of what I would like to achieve via shell.

Comment: Hi Marco, did you ever find a solution for this? I would also like to automate this so that I can take a photo on my phone and copy it directly into my clipboard.

Comment: @ndbroadbent nah, never found a solution

Answer (score 0):

This works for me using the latest version of macOS Mojave.

This code requires [Cliclick](https://www.bluem.net/en/projects/cliclick/) (which is short for “Command-Line Interface Click".) It is a a tiny shell/Terminal application that will emulate mouse clicks or series of mouse clicks (including doubleclicks and control-clicks) at arbitrary screen coordinates. Moreover, it lets you move the mouse, get the current mouse coordinates, press modifier keys etc., Which is free for download and easy to install.

On my system I have. cliclick in the following directory: /usr/local/bin/cliclick. Because of this location, in my AppleScript code and in Terminal app, I need to use the full path to cliclick to call the command. For example: `do shell script "/usr/local/bin/cliclick rc:."` In AppleScript is telling cliclick to right-click.

```
do shell script "/usr/local/bin/cliclick  rc:." -- right-click at current mouse location

delay 1

tell application "System Events"
    key code 124 -- Right Arrow
    delay 0.1
    keystroke "i"
    delay 0.1
    key code 124 -- Right Arrow
    delay 0.1
    keystroke return
end tell
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: I am trying to achieve it without the use of the UI. I would like to type something like this from shell: `importfromiphone > photo.jpg`